# Creating a <div></div> at specific widths or a 2 line box with text wrap

Tags: css, wordpress, width, word-wrap

I am creating a new front page which you can find here  http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/front-page-test/

When the text above the picture is short such as 'Franz Joesf' then my code is

```
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/new-zealand/franz-joesf/">Franz Joesf</a></strong></span>
<div></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/New-Zealand-South-Island-Franz-Joesf-600-by-600-Attempt-2.jpg" alt="New Zealand - Franz Joesf" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
```

When the text above the picture is long such as 'Nearly Dying In The Outback' I use the code

```
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">
<span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/australia/nearly-dying-in-the-outback/">Nearly Dying In The Outback</a></strong></span>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Australia-Northern-Territory-Alice-Springs-Mount-Gillen-600-by-600-1.jpg" alt="Australia - Northern Territory - Alice Springs - Mount Gillen" width="600" height="600" /></div>
```

The difference being that between the image and Franz Joesf there is a blank space. This means when the page is loaded on a desktop at full width all the images line up nicely.

Although for example when the width of the page is between 807 and 867 the text 'Great Australian Bight' spreads across 2 lines while 'Franz Joesf' and 'Kinabatangan' still fits on one line. The code for the 'Great Australian Bight' text and picture is as follows

```
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/great-australian-bight-marine-park-sa/"><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Great Australian Bight</span></a></strong>
<div></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Great-Australian-Bight-600-by-600.jpg" alt="Great Australian Bight" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
```

Is it possible to make it so the code  does not take effect when the width of the page is between 807-867?

Based on the suggestions below I tried the following

```
@media (min-width: 807px) and (max-width: 867px) {
    .IconWidth31PercentTest p:first-child {
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;}
}

<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign IconWidth31PercentTest">

<strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/great-australian-bight-marine-park-sa/"><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Great Australian Bight</span></a></strong>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Great-Australian-Bight-600-by-600.jpg" alt="Great Australian Bight" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
```

Unfortunately it does not achieve the desired effect. As it the home page I don't want the users seeing 'Great Australian Big', it is important they see the full name 'Great Australian Bight'.

Is it possible to set

```
white-space: wrap;
```

And have a text box with 2 rows and when the text exceeds the width of the first row it will flow onto the second row.

I tried to create two rows using

```
@media (min-width: 807px) and (max-width: 867px) {
.IconWidth31PercentTest3 
    p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: wrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

I tried this

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">The Brilliant Times</h2>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="IconWidth31PercentTest3"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/great-australian-bight-marine-park-sa/"><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Great Australian Bight</span></a></strong></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Great-Australian-Bight-600-by-600.jpg" alt="Great Australian Bight" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="IconWidth31PercentTest3"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/new-zealand/franz-joesf/">Franz Joesf</a></strong></span</div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/New-Zealand-South-Island-Franz-Joesf-600-by-600-Attempt-2.jpg" alt="New Zealand - Franz Joesf" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="IconWidth31PercentTest3"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/new-zealand/franz-joesf/">Kinabatangan River</a></strong></span</div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/New-Zealand-South-Island-Franz-Joesf-600-by-600-Attempt-2.jpg" alt="New Zealand - Franz Joesf" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
```

As you can see for yourself at http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/front-page-test/ this definately did not work.

I noticed that the above code had

```
</span
```

I have fixed the issue by putting this code in Additional CSS -

```
@media (min-width: 520px)  {
    .DestinationHeaderWrap {

    line-height: 1.8em;
    height: 4em;
    overflow: hidden;

    text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 100%;}
}
```

Obviously 4/1.8 does not equal 2. When I had 'height:3.6em', the text and picture would look awkwardly close anytime the text wrapped onto the second line.

And having this code on the home page

```
<span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong>Hey, I am Ross. 30 months ago I quit my job in England, jumped on a plane and started a bonkers journey. It has been filled with many ups, downs, twists and turns. Seeing elephants in Borneo was brilliant, getting </strong></span><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong>blacklisted from Vietnam was not so fun, fortunately I got back into the country. Read more about my story <a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/about-me/">here</a>. </strong></span>




<h2 style="text-align: center;">The Brilliant Times</h2>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/great-australian-bight-marine-park-sa/"><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Great Australian Bight</span></a></strong></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Great-Australian-Bight-600-by-600.jpg" alt="Great Australian Bight" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/new-zealand/franz-joesf/">Franz Joesf</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/New-Zealand-South-Island-Franz-Joesf-600-by-600-Attempt-2.jpg" alt="New Zealand - Franz Joesf" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/new-zealand/franz-joesf/">Franz Joesf</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/New-Zealand-South-Island-Franz-Joesf-600-by-600-Attempt-2.jpg" alt="New Zealand - Franz Joesf" width="600" height="600" />

</div>


<h2 style="text-align: center;">The Popular Pages</h2>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/vietnam/teaching-in-vietnam/"><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Teaching in Vietnam</span></a></strong></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Vietnam-Teaching-English-600-by-600-2.jpg" alt="Vietnam - Teaching English - Classroom" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/stray-q-and-a/">Stray Bus Q and A</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/New-Zealand-Stray-Bus-600-by-600-2.jpg" alt="New Zealand - Stray Bus" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/food-costs-in-se-asia/">Food Costs in SE Asia</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/SE-Asia-Food-Prices-Sapa-600-by-600-2.jpg" alt="Sapa BBQ" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">The New Pages</h2>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/philippines/malapascua/"><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Learning to Scuba Dive</span></a></strong></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Philippines-Malapascua-Diving-600-3.jpg" alt="Philippines - Malapascua - Diving" width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/vietnam/blacklisted-from-vietnam/">Teaching in Japan</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Tokyo-600-2.jpg" alt="Japan - Tokyo " width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/vietnam/tam-dao/">Tam Dao</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Tam-Dao-thumbnail-600-600.jpg" alt="Vietnam - Tam Dao " width="600" height="600" />

</div>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">The Awful Times</h2>
<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">

<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/australia/boss-threatened-punch-backpacker/"><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Working For A Violent Boss</span></a></strong></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/home-page-the-crap-times.jpg" alt="Australia Carnival" width="600" height="600" /></div>

<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">
<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/vietnam/blacklisted-from-vietnam/">Blacklisted From Vietnam</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Vietnam-Hanoi-Hoàn-Kiếm-Lake-600-by-600.jpg" alt="Vietnam - Hanoi - Hoàn Kiếm Lake " width="600" height="600" /></div>

<div class="IconWidth31Percent PlaceWhiteIcon VerticalAlign">
<div class="DestinationHeaderWrap"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><a href="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/australia/nearly-dying-in-the-outback/">Nearly Dying In The Outback</a></strong></span></div>
<img class="Thumbnail48PercentPictureSize" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Australia-Northern-Territory-Alice-Springs-Mount-Gillen-600-by-600-1.jpg" alt="Australia - Northern Territory - Alice Springs - Mount Gillen" width="600" height="600" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the only solution I can think of when reviewing your markup was this.

```
@media (min-width: 807px) {
   .IconWidth31Percent p:first-child {
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then reset it after 867px

Comment: Thank you for your help. You directed me the right way and after doing some Googling I managed to solve the problem.